# Customize Lightswitch Autocomplete Footer

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Is it possible to customize the footer of a light-switch auto-complete box?
I want to be able to add a link or a button above the Refresh link. 
Which would allow me to create a new item.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it's not possible to customize the out-of-the-box LightSwitch *AutoCompleteBox* control. You'd have to write a *control extension* that has the same functionality as the ACB, then add your extra link to it.